# Deploy Permission Set Mapping on External Credential

Tags: deployment, namedcredentials

I'm working on a deployment where I am using the new format for Named Credentials with an External Credential. On my external credential, I am using a custom Authentication Protocol with three authentication parameters underneath permission set mapping. When I deployed from the source environment, the parameters did not deploy to the target environment.

When reviewing the underlying xml, it looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ExternalCredential xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
        <authenticationProtocol>Custom</authenticationProtocol>
        <externalCredentialParameters>
            <parameterName>my_permission_set_WnQvjgP1666628587620</parameterName>
            <parameterType>NamedPrincipal</parameterType>
            <principal>my_permission_set</principal>
            <sequenceNumber>1</sequenceNumber>
        </externalCredentialParameters>
        <label>MyExternalCredential</label>
    </ExternalCredential>
```

But on the [ExternalCredential](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.240.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_externalcredential.htm) documentation it looks like it should be shaped like this when pulled through the metadata API:

```
<ExternalCredential xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <label>SampleExternalCredential</label>
    <authenticationProtocol>AwsSv4</authenticationProtocol>
    <externalCredentialParameters>
        <parameterName>Principal</parameterName>
        <parameterType>NamedPrincipal</parameterType>
        <principal>SamplePermissionSet</principal>
        <sequenceNumber>1</sequenceNumber>
    </externalCredentialParameters>
    <externalCredentialParameters>
        <parameterName>AwsService</parameterName>
        <parameterValue>iam</parameterValue>
        <parameterType>AuthParameter</parameterType>
    </externalCredentialParameters>
    <externalCredentialParameters>
        <parameterName>AwsRegion</parameterName>
        <parameterValue>us-east-1</parameterValue>
        <parameterType>AuthParameter</parameterType>
    </externalCredentialParameters>
</ExternalCredential>
```

Is there an additional metadata type I need to pull to ensure that the permission set mappings for the external credential are included? Or is it by design that the credentials would need to be manually updated in each target environment?

Comment: What version is your API?

Comment: Also what command or tool you are using to retrieve the metadata?

Comment: I am using API 56

Comment: I am using ANT (metadata API) to pull. We would use Copado, but our version of copado currently doesn't support the ExternalCredential metadata type.

Comment: I was just using this earlier today and it seemed to work fine if I have the credentials listed under the Custom Headers section. However, if I place them in the Permission Set Mapping against the particular Permission Set, then nothing comes through if I retrieve metadata from the org.

Have you managed to find a resolution to this?

Comment: Nothing elegant, I had to manually update them each environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of V58.0, you can't deploy External Credential Principal Access for either Permission Sets or Profiles

For example, the [Metadata API for PermissionSet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_permissionset.htm?q=permissionset) allows for the deployment of:

- `applicationVisibilities`. e.g. CustomApplication access
- `classAccesses` e.g. ApexClass access
- ...
- `userPermissions` e.g. Run Reports

But no `External Credential Principal Access`.

As you noted in your comments, you need to deploy manually.

---

**UPDATE**: [Metadata API V59.0](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_permissionset.htm?q=permission%20s) resolved this issue. no need to deploy manually if you use MDAPI V59.0 or higher

Answer (score 4):

Starting v59 and greater, you can make use of externalCredentialPrincipalAccesses directly to package and deploy for permission sets. Here is how we will package the 'External Credential Principal Access':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PermissionSet xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<label>SamplePermissionSet</label>
<externalCredentialPrincipalAccesses>
<enabled>true</enabled>
<externalCredentialPrincipal>test-pu</externalCredentialPrincipal>
</externalCredentialPrincipalAccesses>
</PermissionSet>
```

Be advised, here the value of externalCredentialPrincipal tag is formatted like this:

```
<ExternalCredentialName>-<ExternalCredentialParameterName>
```

So, according to example, ExternalCredentialName is 'Test' and ExternalCredentialParameterName is 'pu'.For profiles, it is manual thing at the moment.

Shoutout to Somya Srivastava for this post on the [Known Issues board](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000PG3baUAD/external-credential-principal-access-deployment).

Answer (score 1):

Access to the Principals under an External Credential is managed by `SetupEntityAccess`. Take a look at [this developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/named-credentials/guide/nc-create-oauth-cred.html#create-permissions-for-the-external-credential) for some examples of using Apex to grant access by creating these records.

You may also want to look into the possibilities around retrieving and deploying `SetupEntityAccess`, since it would encompass a much wider range of access rules i.e. anything you can tie to a Permission Set.

Comment: `SetupEntityAccess` is not a Metadata type - not sure how this would be possible